# Is there any way to block people, who use GBWhatsApp, from messaging me on WhatsApp?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Pretty much the title itself. I don't want to block them by simply using the block option in WhatsApp because they will know. I don't know if it's possible or not but if you have any idea on how to do so, please help me out.

Comment: The more important question is: do you already know who uses GBWhatsApp? Because, unless the official WhatsApp app can identify GBWhatsApp users, then there is no way to block them without them knowing. The only feasible workaround is to mute them forever, and possibly archive without opening the chat instead.